# $f(A) \cap f(B) = f(A \cap B)$ if $f$ is a bijection?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I found this statement in a Topology proof - $$f(A) \cap f(B) = f(A \cap B)$$ if $f$ is a bijection

I haven't come across this statement before. Is this some axiom of set theory?

Comment: If $f\colon X\to Y$ is injective, then $\forall A,B\in \mathcal P(X)\left(f[A\cap B]=f[A]\cap f[B]\right)$. It's not an axiom, it's a theorem. You don't need surjectivity.

Comment: This is something that you can prove yourself. Assume that $f$ is a bijection and try to prove that $f(A)\cap f(B) = f(A \cap B)$. Sometimes when reading a proof you have to fill in the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not an axiom.  It is always true that $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$.  To get the reverse inclusion use the fact that $f$ is a bijection.  If $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$ then there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $f(a)=y=f(b)$.  Since $f$ is a bijection we must have $a=b$.  Then $a\in A\cap B$, thus $y=f(a)\in f(A\cap B)$.